# how to calculate row average in panda data frame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have pandas df with column, `T max` & `T min`. I want to calculate `T mean` on next column. I did with this `df['T mean']= df[['T max','T min']].mean(axis=1)` but didnt worked out. I got `T max` as `T mean`. Could anybody help me?

Comment: Please providing a sample dataframe to work with.

Comment: Post raw data, your code, desired output and your erroneous output

Answer (score 1):

I think there is problem with column `T min` - `type` of values is `string`, not numeric. So you need cast it by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

Sample:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'T max':[1,2,3],'T min':['5','6','7']})
print (df)
   T max T min
0      1     5
1      2     6
2      3     7

print (type(df.ix[0,'T min']))
<class 'str'>

df['T mean']= df[['T max','T min']].mean(axis=1) 
print (df)
   T max T min  T mean
0      1     5     1.0
1      2     6     2.0
2      3     7     3.0

#cast column to int
df['T min'] = df['T min'].astype(int)

print (type(df.ix[0,'T min']))
<class 'numpy.int32'>

df['T mean new']= df[['T max','T min']].mean(axis=1) 
print (df)
   T max  T min  T mean  T mean new
0      1      5     1.0         3.0
1      2      6     2.0         4.0
2      3      7     3.0         5.0
```

If `astype` return error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'aaa'

it means in column `T min` is at least one invalid value.

Sample:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'T max':[1,2,3],'T min':['5','6','aaa']})
print (df)
   T max T min
0      1     5
1      2     6
2      3   aaa

df['T mean']= df[['T max','T min']].mean(axis=1) 
print (df)
   T max T min  T mean
0      1     5     1.0
1      2     6     2.0
2      3   aaa     3.0

#check invalid rows where is bad value in T min
print (df[ pd.to_numeric(df['T min'], errors='coerce').isnull()])
   T max T min  T mean
2      3   aaa     3.0

#replace invlid value to NaN
df['T min'] = pd.to_numeric(df['T min'], errors='coerce')

df['T mean new']= df[['T max','T min']].mean(axis=1) 
print (df)
   T max  T min  T mean  T mean new
0      1    5.0     1.0         3.0
1      2    6.0     2.0         4.0
2      3    NaN     3.0         3.0
```